# Extremely long refreshing of ICollectionView

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, filtering

I'm using `ICollectionView` to display, filter and sort items of a `TreeView` in `WPF`. Each tree item has its own collection of sub-items created in the following way:

```
children = new ObservableCollection<MyTreeItem>();
visibleChildren = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(children);
```

The filtering consists of two steps. The first one is to go through the whole hierarchy (~600 items total) and chooses, which items are to be displayed and which ones should be filtered out.

```
private static bool RecursiveApply(StructureTreeBaseItem root,
    StructureTreeFilterInfo info) {

    bool show = false;

    foreach (var child in root.Children)
        show &= RecursiveApply(child, info);

    if (!show)
        show = root.MatchesFilter(info);

    root.IsFilteredOut = !show;

    return show;
}
```

The second step is to recursively call `Refresh` on all `ICollectionView`s to allow them react to changes.

```
root.RefreshChildren();

// ->

public void RefreshChildren() {

    if (ChildrenChanged)
         VisibleChildren.Refresh();

    foreach (var child in VisibleChildren)
        (child as StructureTreeBaseItem).RefreshChildren();
    }
```

I'm a little bit concerned about performance of such scenario. I made some tests in similar conditions and it turned out, that building the tree structure from scratch takes around 100-150ms, applying filter usually costs no more than 50ms, but recursive calls to `Refresh` takes 600ms and more.

From what I found, it seems, that it makes a lot more sense to rebuild the tree structure from scratch each time the filter is applied instead of using the `ICollectionView` features to do it. This seems wrong. Am I doing something not the way I should or maybe it's a general problem with `ICollectionView` and I should solve this problem in another way?

---

**Edit**: (in response to comments)

This is a relevant part of structure of my tree in XAML - nothing special :) The rest is purely presentational.

```
<TreeView x:Name="tsdTree" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="250" Margin="0, 2, 0, 0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=StructureView}" BorderThickness="0">
    <TreeView.Resources>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding VisibleChildren}" DataType="{x:Type st:StructureTreeItem}">
            (...)
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding VisibleChildren}" DataType="{x:Type st:StructureTreeFolder}">
            (...)
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: It is not the general problem with ICollectionView therefore I would like to ask you if you could upload your project somewhere online so I may check it out. I would gladly like to help you out with controls since I work as controls develeoper :) Just give me the complete code somehow so I may run it and see where you stuck at. From the text you posted above it is hard for me to see what exactly you doing there. Code will give us all a clear picture. Thanks.

Comment: lol but I ment you could upload the project online so I can download it and run it :)

Comment: I'm affraid, that I cannot disclose the whole code. I can provide more information about my implementation if needed though.

Comment: Ok, then let me ask few questions about this in order to get a clearer picture. Have you tried running your RecursiveApply method and after it you just called Refresh on TreeView? Just one call? Try it out and let me know about changes please. Futhermore could you post your model (means how you generate data for the TreeView in your ObservableCollection<MyTreeItem>) and could you post how you define the TreeView in XAML please.

Comment: After calling `RecursiveApply` I call `RefreshChildren` on the root item of my hierarchy, which - as you can see in my code - results in calling `Refresh` on item's ICollectionViews (recursively). The question is, whether Refresh on TreeView will result in refreshing the views. Generating the tree structure is a lot of code, but there's nothing special there, I just instantiate items and fill their Children. I'll edit my post to include the relevant parts of the TreeView.

Comment: I ment you call just refresh once and not to call your RefreshChildren method that recursively runs though children. I am asking you to not call that recursive refresh process you wrote. Call the refresh of the top most collection and tell me what happens. Do not execute your custom RefreshChildren. Any changes?

Comment: It does not work, only root hierarchy is being refreshed. All other are displayed, while they shouldn't have been.

Comment: Ok I will take a look at this later today.

Comment: Hey, could you please post the code of ICollectionView and ViewModel?